# scrollview is hiding my password indicators

Tags: android, xml

Hello guys i am facing an issue i want to apply scrollview in this xml because its a registration page and for better ui I need to apply scrollview there once keyboard open user scroll up and down for filling fields but when I applied scrollview there my tab indicators are invisible and I tried to visible but nothing idea was working here is my xml

```
        /*    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="9.15">

            <include layout="@layout/view_header"></include>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/phone"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobilenum"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_mobileno"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:focusable="true"

                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_mobilenum" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

           <!-- username-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/username"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_username"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:focusable="true"


                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_username" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--password-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/password"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
                <!--passwordedit text-->
                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--android:layout_weight="2.5"-->
                <!--android:weightSum="2.5">-->
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:maxLength="16"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <!--</LinearLayout>-->
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- password indicator-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >
                <!-- dumpy value-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"

                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:weightSum="4"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordredindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected"

                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            />
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordyellowindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            />
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordblueindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            />
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordgreenindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected"
                            android:layout_weight="1"

                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--indicator closed here-->

            <!--password indicator strenght-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|right"
                >

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:id="@+id/signup_passwordremarks" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--password indicator strenght-->

            <!--Repeat Password-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/repeat_password"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_reconfirmpassword"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_reconfirmpassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_Repeatpassword" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- cnic-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/cnic"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_cnic"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_cnic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:focusable="true"

                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_cnic" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        <!--email address-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/email"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_emailaddress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_emailaddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:focusable="true"

                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>




            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>*/
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code..

tested & working fine.

```
`<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/view_header"></include>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/phone" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobilenum"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_mobileno"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

                        android:hint="@string/hint_mobilenum"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:singleLine="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- username-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/username" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_username"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"


                        android:hint="@string/hint_username"
                        android:singleLine="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--password-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/password" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <!--passwordedit text-->
                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--android:layout_weight="2.5"-->
                <!--android:weightSum="2.5">-->
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLength="16"
                        android:singleLine="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <!--</LinearLayout>-->
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- password indicator-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">
                <!-- dumpy value-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordredindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"                               android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordyellowindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"                                android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordblueindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/signup_passwordgreenindicator"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/passwordstengthunselected"

                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--indicator closed here-->

            <!--password indicator strenght-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/signup_passwordremarks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--password indicator strenght-->

            <!--Repeat Password-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/repeat_password" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_reconfirmpassword"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_reconfirmpassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_Repeatpassword"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:singleLine="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- cnic-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/cnic" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_cnic"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_cnic"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

                        android:hint="@string/hint_cnic"
                        android:singleLine="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--email address-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/email" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_emailaddress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/signup_emailaddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

                        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:singleLine="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

> Or if you want to scroll on focus, add below attribute in Activity tag in Manifest file

```
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
```

Comment: Dude i used above mentioned xml but its not fixed my problem  my password tab indicators are not visible you can also check by run this xml